# Array of objects in Cython: Looking to read the documentation first

Tags: cython

I just started with Cython and I'm feeling a bit lost. I want to create an array of objects, and from reading StackExchange I'm finding multiple ways to do things and multiple types (and meanings of the words) array / list / pointer.

So before I ask a stupid question, I feel like I should have a proper read at the manual, but I can't for the life of me find a complete manual going over all of the possible ways to do this in Cython. Could anyone direct me to the right resource please?

For background, I am fluent in Python and C++.

Comment: You are talking about Python objects?  So regardless of the structure, the `cython` code will have use Python functions (from its c-api) to reference and use them.  I wouldn't expect to get much of a speed up.  If you generate the highlighted html, you'll see a lot of bright yellow.

Comment: @hpaulj Does a cdef class count as a Python object? It's those I wanted to have a list/array/watchamacallit of

Comment: @Gabi Yes, a `cdef` class is a Python object. There isn't really a good solution to this - just using a normal Python list (`[ o1, o2, o3 ]`) is as good as you can do